# What's the use of dbms_scheduler.auto_purge()?

Tags: oracle, plsql

What's the use of `call dbms_scheduler.auto_purge()`? The procedure is not listed in the official PL/SQL Packages and Types Reference.

When I execute this function, what will happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never used it. But, here's what Morgan's Library and Burleson Consulting say about it (didn't find any reference in "official" Oracle documentation).

> AUTO_PURGE [purges](https://www.morganslibrary.org/reference/pkgs/dbms_scheduler.html#sched09) from the logs based on class and global log_history.

> The [AUTO_PURGE](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_advanced_purging_window_logs.htm) procedure uses the log_history values defined at the scheduler, job class and job log_history level to determine which logs should be purged. This procedure runs as part of the scheduled purge process, but it can also be run manually.